# Why my Bootstrap Modal loads incomplete after using clear Interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

Every 2 seconds I update a table on my page. This table has a Modal button that also contains information and therefore it is also updated every 2 seconds. The problem is that the info in the Modal doesn't load after using clear Interval. (No need to say that I do need to use clear Interval because Modal doesn't work with the table updating constantly). The code is as follow

```
    var myTimer;

    function startTimer() {
      myTimer = setInterval(function () {
        somefunction_to_updatetable();
      }, 2000);
    };
    
    function stopTimer() {
      clearInterval(myTimer);
    };
      
    $(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#idModal', function (e) {
      stopTimer();
    });

      window.onload = function() {
        startTimer();
      };
```

In this code, when loading the page `setInterval` is defined with `window.onload`. It starts updating info in the table every 2 seconds. When I click the Modal button, `stopTimer` is read and `setInterval` is cleared. The Modal opens but the info is not there, only info that is not part of somefunction_to_updatetable() is present in the Modal... how can I fix this? I feel it is straightforward from where I am but I really cannot find a way

Comment: how to your load info in your modal ? what jquery function you are using. Also please share `somefunction_to_updatetable` what in there related to loading the data in the modal.

Comment: Thanks...you nailed it. the issue was in somefunction_to_updatetable. I was removing the div where my modal button was. I needed to add specific ids or classes to specific divs that I wanted to update. I will find some time to update my post with the solution

Comment: Glad to hear that we're able to spot the issue and is now working as expected.